# Change list, that you are iterating through, in that loop

Tags: python, loops

In my case I have a for loop, looping through a list, but I want to change that list in said loop.
After that I want the for loop to iterate through the new list.

```
li = [4,5,6,7,8,9]
for item in li:
    #do something

    if item == 5:
        #now continue iterating through this loop and not the old one
        li = [9,9,9,9,9,9]
```

How can I do something like that?

Comment: All advice is not to mutate the list you are iterating through, because it is very hard to reason about what happens if you do.

Comment: That's not mutating the list; it's just assigning a new value to the name `li`. Since the `for` loop already has an instance of an iterator for the original loop, this really doesn't have any affect.

Answer (score 0):

Allthough @BoarGules's comment is correct, you may solve your problem using enumerate.

```
li = [4,5,6,7,8,9]
for i, item in enumerate(li):
    print(li[i])
    if li[i] == 5:
        li = [9,9,9,9,9,9]
```

This outputs:

```
>4
>5
>9
>9
>9
```

Comment: The question is, is this a documented behavior of enumerate(), or are you just exploiting a particular implementation that could change tomorrow. The description of enumerate() does not explicitly state that what you do is guaranteed to happen that way: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't change the list through iteration. I would use indexing:

```
for i in range(len(li)):
    if li[i] == 5:
        li = len(li) * [9]
```

Answer (score 0):

To see why this doesn't work, a `for` loop is equivalent to a `while` loop like this:

```
# for x in y:
#    ...
itr = iter(y)
while True:
    try:
        x = next(itr)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    ...
```

If you assign something new to `y`, the loop isn't affected, because it only uses the iterator over the original value assigned to `y`, not the name `y` itself.

However, if you *do* mutate the list in the body of the loop, the iterator might return a value you don't expect. If you need to change the iterable, it's best to get the iterator yourself.

```
li = [4,5,6,7,8,9]
itr = iter(li)
while True:
    try:
        item = next(itr)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    #do something

    if item == 5:
        #now continue iterating through this loop and not the old one
        itr = iter([9,9,9,9,9])
```